# Get two values by tag name at the same time?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have several XML files and want to get two values of each product. I could do it like this:

```
$doc = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$items = $doc->xpath("//$tagName");

$titles = array();
$prices = array();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $node = dom_import_simplexml($item);

    if(strcasecmp($tagName, "title") == 0){
        array_push($titles, $node->textContent);
    }

    if(strcasecmp($tagName, "price") == 0){
        array_push($prices, $node->textContent);
    }
}
```

But this is way too precarious way I think. I want to be safe that both values form a pair. Because it could be that one product doesn't contain a price or title, which is unthinkable, but it could be! (The files aren't from me!

So is there a way to get the tag `name`and `preis` of each `product` at one time, as pair? - Because this is the only way to be safe!

Greetings and Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here is. You're converting the DOM into SimpleXML to use Xpath. This is not needed. DOM has the `DOMXpath` class and `DOMXpath::evaluate()` is more powerful then `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`.

Xpath can do quite a lot. For example you could fetch any product that has an `name` and a `preis`:

`//product[normalize-string(name) != '' and normalize-string(preis) != '']`

But to get the values connected you will need to fetch and iterate the `product` nodes, then execute additional Xpath expressions to fetch the values.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$result = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//product') as $product) {
  $result[] = [
    'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $product),
    'price' => $xpath->evaluate('number(preis)', $product)
  ];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "Battlefield 1"
    ["price"]=>
    float(80)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "Battlefield 2"
    ["price"]=>
    float(180)
  }
  ...
```

`string(name)` fetches all `name` child nodes and cast the result into a string. In Xpath that means that the text content of the first node in the list is returned. If the list was empty you get an empty string.

`number(preis)` fetches all `preis` child nodes and casts the text content of the first node into a numer. The result will be `0` if here was no matching node.

Answer (score 1):

One recommendation is to use [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of [simplexml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). I feel it's more expressive.

--- Later Edit ---

Here's the simplexml implementation

```
$string = <<<EOS
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Battlefield 1</name>
    <preis>80</preis>
    <sterne>3</sterne>
    <desc>Dies ist ein Text</desc>
    <link>https://www.google.de/</link>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Battlefield 2</name>
    <preis>180</preis>
    <sterne>3</sterne>
    <desc>Dies ist ein Text</desc>
    <link>https://www.google.de/</link>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Battlefield 3</name>
    <preis>280</preis>
    <sterne>3</sterne>
    <desc>Dies ist ein Text</desc>
    <link>https://www.google.de/</link>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Battlefield 4</name>
    <preis>380</preis>
    <sterne>3</sterne>
    <desc>Dies ist ein Text</desc>
    <link>https://www.google.de/</link>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Battlefield 5</name>
    <preis>480</preis>
    <sterne>3</sterne>
    <desc>Dies ist ein Text</desc>
    <link>https://www.google.de/</link>
  </product>
</products>
EOS;

$doc = simplexml_load_string($string);

// get a list of products
$products = $doc->xpath('/products/product');

// iterate of the list
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $name = $product->name->__toString();
    $price = $product->preis->__toString();

    echo $name . ' = ' . $price . PHP_EOL;
}
```

--- end of later edit ---

Here's an working example:

```
<?php

$string = <<<EOS
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Battlefield 1</name>
    <preis>80</preis>
    <sterne>3</sterne>
    <desc>Dies ist ein Text</desc>
    <link>https://www.google.de/</link>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Battlefield 2</name>
    <preis>180</preis>
    <sterne>3</sterne>
    <desc>Dies ist ein Text</desc>
    <link>https://www.google.de/</link>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Battlefield 3</name>
    <preis>280</preis>
    <sterne>3</sterne>
    <desc>Dies ist ein Text</desc>
    <link>https://www.google.de/</link>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Battlefield 4</name>
    <preis>380</preis>
    <sterne>3</sterne>
    <desc>Dies ist ein Text</desc>
    <link>https://www.google.de/</link>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Battlefield 5</name>
    <preis>480</preis>
    <sterne>3</sterne>
    <desc>Dies ist ein Text</desc>
    <link>https://www.google.de/</link>
  </product>
</products>
EOS;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXml($string);
$products = $doc->getElementsByTagName('product');

$index = 0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo 'Showing information for product #' . $index++ . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($product->childNodes as $property) {
        if ($property instanceof DOMText) continue;
        echo ' ->' . $property->localName . ' = ' . $property->textContent . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need one for [simplexml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: I would be very thankful if you could give me one for simplexml.
But aside from this could you please explain how you get the price and name? - Because `$property->localName` and `$property->textContent` are not the name either the price?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You have now an example with simplexml